# Rails HABTM nested array in joins query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm creating a REST api with Rails 5 that involves `authors` and `media` with a `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship between them.

Here are the models:

```
class Author < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :media
end

class Medium < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :authors
end
```

and here are the migrations:

```
class CreateMedia < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :media do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.text :description
      t.datetime :published_date
      t.string :type
      t.integer :pages
      t.time :length
      t.string :site
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateAuthors < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :authors do |t|
      t.string :first_name
      t.string :last_name
      t.text :bio
      t.string :site    
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateJoinTableMediumAuthor < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_join_table :media, :authors do |t|
      t.index [:medium_id, :author_id]
      t.index [:author_id, :medium_id]
    end
  end
end
```

The issue I'm having is I want to nest the authors in the media when making a general query and vice-versa, similar to what you can do in Laravel with Collections. I've looked everywhere and can't seem to find a solution.

To make it clearer here's a current example JSON response for a query for all media (`Medium.all.includes(:authors)`):

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "The Personal MBA",
    "description": "Master the art of business",
    "published_date": "2017-03-31T14:51:46.675Z",
    "pages": 400,
    "length": null,
    "site": null,
    "created_at": "2017-03-31T14:51:46.687Z",
    "updated_at": "2017-03-31T14:51:46.687Z"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "title": "The Circle",
    "description": "A chlling and prophetic tale",
    "published_date": "2017-03-31T14:51:46.690Z",
    "pages": 333,
    "length": null,
    "site": null,
    "created_at": "2017-03-31T14:51:46.691Z",
    "updated_at": "2017-03-31T14:51:46.691Z"
  },
]
```

where as I would like a response like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "The Personal MBA",
    "description": "Master the art of business",
    "published_date": "2017-03-31T14:51:46.675Z",
    "pages": 400,
    "length": null,
    "site": null,
    "authors": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "first_name": "Josh",
        "last_name": "Kaufman",
        "bio": "A business writer",
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "first_name": "Dave",
        "last_name": "Eggers",
        "bio": "fiction",
      }
    ]
    "created_at": "2017-03-31T14:51:46.687Z",
    "updated_at": "2017-03-31T14:51:46.687Z"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "title": "The Circle",
    "description": "A chlling and prophetic tale",
    "published_date": "2017-03-31T14:51:46.690Z",
    "pages": 333,
    "length": null,
    "site": null,
    "authors": [
      {
        "id": 2,
        "first_name": "Dave",
        "last_name": "Eggers",
        "bio": "fiction",
      }
    ],
    "created_at": "2017-03-31T14:51:46.691Z",
    "updated_at": "2017-03-31T14:51:46.691Z"
  },
]
```

The difference beings the `authors` array included in the response.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Medium < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :authors

  def details
    as_json(
     include: {authors: except: [:created_at, :updated_at]}
    )
  end
end
```

Now call this `details` method. Example `Medium.first.details`, you will have your authors included in that object.

Comment: Okay so the issue is it has to do with the serializer, not the Models themselves like I originally imagined. As a note this can be built into any `@json` response or into the serializer for the objects themselves.